# Can anyone help me figuring out what's wrong with my drive structure?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, partition, mojave, apfs

I've realized something is wrong with my disks/drives/partitions structure when I tried countless installing Windows via Bootcamp but it would always fail.

Please take a look at what I have:

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is it. Please let me know if you guys need more information. I just wish to clean up the mess and reset the disk structure to the same one that I'd be getting with a clean install. For instance, I don't know what that "VM" volume is. I dont have a VM. I feel it is all a mess.
Also disk2 is just a SD card, nothing wrong with it. Problem lies with disk1.

Comment: Disk 2 looks fine and you could always eject it / wipe it if you don’t want to put boot camp on it. Where do you want to have the boot camp installed?

Comment: Disk2 is just a SD card, ignore it. The problem is within the main SSD, where I'm trying to install windows in.

Comment: Cool - If you follow Apple’s guide on boot camp - what step do you get an error and what is that error? The first image shows you skipped some steps or are following another guide. Before you can get to windows install the container disk0s2 would be shrunk and a new partition made.

Comment: I followed the regular bootcamp assistant process. I didnt do anything out of the ordinary there. When it booted into windows, in the setup, I just erased the bootcamp partition and created a new one because it also wouldnt install otherwise

Comment: It’s tough, so I’m not at all criticizing you - it would be a book to cover all your steps, so you chose the most relevant items you felt could help us help you. Let’s see what others think or have for an answer.